# Is it possible to retrieve the condition map of a defn'd var?

Tags: clojure

If I've defined a function with `defn` and a condition map containing `:pre` and `:post` forms, how can I retrieve that condition map? I notice that

```
(meta #'fn-name)
```

doesn't contain the condition map. I'm specifically looking for the `:pre` conditions (in order to derive a predicate that's equivalent to them but doesn't assert). Is there any way to recover them other than walking the function body looking for `assert`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, they aren't stored anywhere after processing the `fn` macro. They're prepended/appended directly to the `body` of the function as asserts. You can check [the relevant source lines in `fn`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.6.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L4184-L4196).

As a workaround, you could probably write your own variant of `defn` that grabs the `:pre` and `:post` conditions and stores them as metadata.

Comment: Thanks DaoWen! I'd seen the lines in `fn`, but somehow hoped that defn would have additional machinery to store them. I'm guessing that adding them would add memory overhead, and that's why they're not retained. Thanks for the idea of the workaround!